# Maximum Spacing between supports of Schedule 80 on flat roof

Tags: electrical

I have 2" schedule 80 running #3 wire. What would be the spacing distance between Uni to Uni on a flat roof. I am in southern CA where the flat roof gets very hot in the summer and I don't want the conduit to sag. Also, does anyone know the code I would reference for that distance?

Answer (score 1):

According to [NEC 2020 352.30](https://up.codes/viewer/florida/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#352.30), the maximum distance between supports varies based on conduit size:

- 1/2" - 1" - 3 feet
- 1-1/4" - 2" - 5 feet
- 2-1/2" - 3" - 6 feet
- 3-1/2" - 5" - 7 feet
- 6" - 8 feet

Heat *might* be an issue. Official rules are maximum temperature 122 F (50 C). Except for Death Valley, you should be OK outside in general. But inside an attic it can get hotter than outside, and depending on roofing type, outside *might* be an issue too. Which makes rigid metal conduit worth considering - no temperature concerns and up to 10 feet between supports.